# How to get OVH service account identity?

Tags: ovh

According to [the OVH docs](https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-manage-service-account?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0059343) you can create a service account via oauth2 and then request `/me/api/oauth2/client/{clientId}` to get the identity info. I've created a service account with `authorization_code` flow but when I make the API call I get `identity: null` in the response.

Does that mean identities only created for service accounts created with `client_credentials` flow? If so, how can I create an identity for my service account?